# Variadic templates with constants

Tags: c++, templates, visual-studio-2013, variadic-templates

I'm doing some experimenting with metaprogramming and variadic templates, and I'm having trouble with some confusing behaviour. I've stripped it down to a minimum working example, but essentially I want to keep track of how many recursive calls I'm making. I want to do this by making the first template parameter an integer, while the second template parameter is a variadic list. In simplest form it looks like this:

```
template<typename... List>
struct initial_call{
     static const int val = next_call<0, List...>::val;
};

template<int D, typename... List>
struct next_call {
     static const int val = D;
};
```

So ignoring the fact that this code is pointless, it doesn't compile on VS2013, claiming "unexpected type 'List", on the line inside the definition of initial_call. Without the integer in front, it works fine. So is there a way to combine variadic templates with integer template parameters?

Comment: Sorry @cdhowie, I've edited.

Comment: `next_call` should be before `initial_call`

Comment: After placing `next_call` before `initial_call`, it [works for me](http://ideone.com/PV41Hc).

Comment: Gah, thanks @PiotrS. Can't believe I missed that.

Comment: Looks like it was parsing the initializer as `(next_call < 0), List` and it broke there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want something like this (counting the number of types):

```
#include <iostream>

// More than one type: Increment size and consume.
template<size_t N, typename T, typename... List>
struct calculate_list_size {
     static const size_t value = calculate_list_size<N + 1, List...>::value;
};

// Last type: Increment size and terminate.
template<size_t N, typename T>
struct calculate_list_size<N, T> {
     static const size_t value = N + 1;
};


// Forward to calculate_list_size.
template<typename... List>
struct list_size {
     static const size_t value = calculate_list_size<0, List...>::value;
};

// Empty list
template<>
struct list_size<> {
     static const size_t value = 0;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << list_size<char, short, int>::value << '\n';
    std::cout << list_size<>::value << '\n';
}
```

Comment: That's perfect, thank you! I ended up figuring out the syntax error, that was throwing me off, but it's nice to have a full example.